# Go to specific row number in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way in Excel to go to a specific row number? For example I need to find an alternate way to not have to scroll but rather can immediately go to row # 3000

Answer (score 127, accepted):

There is a little box next to the formula bar in your toolbar, if you are in the first cell and row it should read A1, so to go to row 3000 type A3000 and press enter

Comment: My Microsoft (R) Excel(R) for Mac 2011 Version 14.3.2 just crashed when I used the function a few times. This was the first newly recovered feature i liked about excel in many years and its broken. Oh Microsoft though art strange ...

Comment: If the formula bar is missing, as in later Excel versions, goto `View > Show > Formula Bar`.

Answer (score 64):

### Ctrl-G

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> > Specify row (`38:38`), column (`C:D`), cell (`A1`) or range (`Range1`) > <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Of course, if you want to go to row 38, you can type `A38` instead of `38:38` for fewer keystrokes.

Note: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> is the hotkey of **Go To**

---

### Little box

[Alternatively,](https://superuser.com/a/440450/43356) **the little box at the left of the formula bar** is another option. Similarly, you can specify row, column, cell or range there.

Comment: I think to reach row 512 I used to be able to do "CNTRL G" and then 512.  Now, it is crucial to type A512.... not sure why excel went in the 'wrong direction' on this; certainly A512 should work, but why it doesn't interpret 512 correctly from the 'context' .... just not sure!

Answer (score 5):

1. Ctrl + G
2. A[row number]  Eg: A1245

Comment: Hi and welcome to Super User! Thanks for taking the time to answer this question. Unfortunately, this solution is already clearly mentioned in one of the existing answers. An up vote for that answer would thus be likely more appropriate in this case.

Comment: @Anaksunaman That answer didn't solve my problem.  It was poorly written. I couldn't understand what do to.  It didn't solve the problem.